# oAuth Problems with CALLBACKURL for android/twitter dev (Version 2.3.3)

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, twitter-oauth, signpost

I'm using the Twitter oAuth system for an app of mine, specifically folllowing this tutorial: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2012/01/02/learning-android-authenticating-with-twitter-using-oauth/.  I seem to be getting an error based on my callback URL and I just cannot find a solution or proper information anywhere on how to do this properly.  My app's name is chirpee, ill post the code and errors, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: alot of tutorials have random twitter urls for the CALLBACKURL like "app://twitter" when i try to set them on my app page through twitter developers they are "invalid URL's".  For the time being i have the CALLBACKURL set to http://crownseal.ca (random site) on both the developers page for my app and in the code.

```
package me.chirpee.tom;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;   
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Chirpee extends Activity 
{
    //variables
    private String CALLBACKURL = "http://crownseal.ca";
    private String consumerKey = "----";
    private String consumerSecret = "----";
    private OAuthProvider httpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
    private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer httpOauthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      Button oauth = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      oauth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
      {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
          try 
          {
            String authUrl = httpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(httpOauthConsumer, CALLBACKURL);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl));
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
          } 
          catch (Exception e) 
          {
            Log.w("oauth fail", e);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        }
      });//end onClickListener()

    }//end onCreate()




    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
      super.onNewIntent(intent);

      Log.w("redirect-to-app", "going to save the key and secret");

      Uri uri = intent.getData();
      if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACKURL)) {

          String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

          try {
              // this will populate token and token_secret in consumer

              httpOauthprovider.retrieveAccessToken(httpOauthConsumer, verifier);
              String userKey = httpOauthConsumer.getToken();
              String userSecret = httpOauthConsumer.getTokenSecret();

              // Save user_key and user_secret in user preferences and return
              SharedPreferences settings = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("your_app_prefs", 0);
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
              editor.putString("user_key", userKey);
              editor.putString("user_secret", userSecret);
              editor.commit();

          } catch (Exception e) {

          }
      } else {
          // Do something if the callback comes from elsewhere
      }
    }
```

}

and in my manifest file, i have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="me.chirpee.tom"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Chirpee" 
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">

        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


        <!-- Used for OAuth callback -->
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="crownseal.ca" />
         </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and my errors are as follows:

```
04-20 18:01:26.017: D/AndroidRuntime(1128): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-20 18:01:26.017: D/AndroidRuntime(1128): CheckJNI is ON
04-20 18:01:26.726: D/AndroidRuntime(1128): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
04-20 18:01:26.766: D/AndroidRuntime(1128): Shutting down VM
04-20 18:01:26.786: D/dalvikvm(1128): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 71% free 297K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+1ms
04-20 18:01:26.786: D/dalvikvm(1128): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-20 18:01:26.816: I/AndroidRuntime(1128): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
04-20 18:01:27.236: D/AndroidRuntime(1138): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-20 18:01:27.236: D/AndroidRuntime(1138): CheckJNI is ON
04-20 18:01:27.897: D/AndroidRuntime(1138): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
04-20 18:01:27.937: I/ActivityManager(60): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=me.chirpee.tom/.Chirpee } from pid 1138
04-20 18:01:27.947: W/redirect-to-app(1099): going to save the key and secret
04-20 18:01:27.957: D/AndroidRuntime(1138): Shutting down VM
04-20 18:01:27.977: D/dalvikvm(1138): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 69% free 319K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+2ms
04-20 18:01:27.977: D/dalvikvm(1138): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-20 18:01:28.007: I/AndroidRuntime(1138): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: api.twitter.com
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at me.chirpee.tom.Chirpee$1.onClick(Chirpee.java:41)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099): Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: api.twitter.com
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:497)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:406)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:387)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:152)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthProvider.sendRequest(DefaultOAuthProvider.java:48)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:177)
04-20 18:01:33.676: W/oauth fail(1099):     ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this may be related but I didn't see the `Internet` Permission in the manifest file